# Import image Android Sudio

Tags: android-studio, path, android-drawable

I got a school project where i need to make a cooking app, I struggle with programmaticaly importing an image to get a preview of the dish in my class.

The images are located in the drawable-v24 folder but i can't figure out ou to get the right path to it.

I want it to be a Drawable to create an image view in my layout.

```
package com.example.projet_info0306;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;




public class Recette {
    private String nom;
    private Etape[] steps;
    private Drawable Demo;

    public Recette(String n,Etape[] e,String PathImg,) {
        nom=n;
        steps=e;
        Demo= Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/"+PathImg+".png");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the Image in your App, just go to your activity_main.xml, add an ImageView to the layout and give it an ID.

You can now either link up the image statically in the XML by unsing the `android:src` tag or you can do it programatically by using:

```
Imageview imageview;
imageview = findViewByID(R.id.[yourID]);
imageview.setDrawable(R.drawable.[yourDrawable]);
```

NOTE: The code snippet you showed is in a normal Class not in an Activity. If you want to add one just go to your projects folder and right click on App. Android Studio will then lets you create an Activity. Or if your are not that far in the process, just create a new project and add an Activty from the beginning.